# sql replace for wordpress database

Tags: sql, replace, phpmyadmin

I'm in the process of moving my wordpress installation over to a new server and a new domain.  I have all the files moved over and I have a new database created and changed the settings in `wp-config.php` to reflect this.  However, upon importing everything, it's still pointing to my previous domain.  I'm looking to cut ALL ties to my previous domain, so I want to do an SQL query (through `phpMyAdmin`) to replace EVERY instance of my old domain and change them to my new domain.

I've stumbled upon the following:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://oldlink.com', 'http://newlink.com');
```

I've tried replacing the `wp_table` instances with `*` and it throws a syntax error.  Can any of you fine intelligent people help me out with altering this query? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updating it via SQL will be way too much of a pain because ou have ~13 tables (more if you have plugins) each with many columns.

I have two ways of doing this

**If you have plugins that created their own tabes:**

Export the entiredatabase into a SQL File, open up in a text edior and do a find and replace on the following

oldomain.com/path/to/wordpressinstall

newdomain.com/path/to/install

Chances are you will just need olddomain.com and new domain.com without any sub folders. Its **super** important that you do not include anything such as http:// or www as well as any trailing slashes at the end. This will match 100% of the urls regardless of if they look like this:

http://domain.com/wp-content/lol.jpg
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/

Once you are done, delete your old DB and import this one.

**If its just a simple wordpress install**

Set the urls in your wp-config file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Now that you have hard coded the site url you can log into your new site, download a plugin called search and replace and run the above search/replace with the nice GUI interface.